# Override colorscheme

Tags: vim, colors, color-scheme

I often find myself wanting to change just something little in a colorscheme, but i don't want to edit the original file. I tried putting my change in '~/.vim/after/colors/blah.vim', but that doesn't work for me.

---

Example, I want to change the CursorLine highlight in BusyBee.vim..

~/.vim/colors/BusyBee.vim

I create the file '~/.vim/after/colors/BusyBee.vim' and add this:

```
hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none
```

However, i don't see the change. Of course it works if i change the line in the originial BusyBee.vim, but like i said i'd prefer not to do that.

Doing...

```
:colo Busy<TAB>
```

Shows me...

```
BusyBee  BusyBee
```

Comment: Why not just copy the theme and edit the copy?

Comment: Less work when updating. The idea is to have my changes override the theme's so i can just update the theme without having to merge my changes in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [AfterColors.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641), it will enable you to to use the `~/.vim/after/colors/BusyBee.vim` method.

Comment: Pretty late to this party, but for reference, AfterColors.vim is now mirrored (by me) on Github https://github.com/tsiemens/vim-aftercolors, such that people can just add it to their plugin list.

I just found this thread yesterday, and created that repo. Figured I should make note of it.

Answer (score 51):

You asked what I'm looking for today. I found a simpler solution than those presented here. I want transparent background instead of the black background from the theme, while simply overriding the color after the `colorscheme` statement in `.vimrc` doesn't work and installing a plugin just for that is weird. Here is what I did:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Normal ctermbg=None
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight NonText ctermbg=None
```

Why does it work? I guess that vim does something besides just read your `colorscheme` statement and load the statement and then read your `highlight` statement and change the color. Anyway it seems like vim only change the color scheme after reading the config files. So I provide a hook, that will change the colors every time the color scheme is changed. A nice side effect is, this works even if you switch your color scheme (you could do an `if` block if you want to).

Comment: Hi, I'm using the jellybeans theme and want to have a pure black backgruond, but it's gray actually. I've added the lines you proposed to the .vimrc, but nothing happens... what do I do?

Comment: Do you have a transparent terminal? The black background is transparent so you wouldn't get real black if your terminal is transparent. Try `:highlight Normal ctermbg=blue` during a Vim session and see if it sets your background to blue. If it does, I think you'll have to change your terminal settings. Or maybe there is something that I don't know of.

Comment: I've tried it and only the first and the last line are set to blue, not the whole window.

Comment: I had no idea that was possible to `autocmd Colorscheme`.
just my 2 cents, for me the background transparency worked using `guibg` instead of `ctermbg`, maybe help some noob like me in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have 'colorscheme BusyBee' in my .vimrc. I like to switch colorscheme now and then, so i want to "fix" the actual theme.

I came up with this solution, not the prettiest, but whatever.

```
function! FixColorscheme() " {{{
    echo "fixing colorscheme"
    if has("gui_running")
        if (g:colors_name =~ "busybee")
            hi Folded        guibg=#001336 guifg=#003DAD gui=none
            hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none

        elseif (g:colors_name =~ "256-jungle")
            hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none

        elseif (g:colors_name =~ "xoria256")
            hi Folded        guibg=#001336 guifg=#003DAD gui=none cterm=none
            "hi Folded         ctermbg=234  ctermfg=25    cterm=none
        endif
    elseif &t_Co == 256
        if (g:colors_name =~ "busybee")
            hi Folded        guibg=#001336 guifg=#003DAD gui=none
            hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none

        elseif (g:colors_name =~ "256-jungle")
            hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none

        elseif (g:colors_name =~ "xoria256")
            hi Folded         ctermbg=234  ctermfg=25    cterm=none
            hi CursorLine    cterm=none
        "else
            "hi CursorLine     ctermbg=0                  cterm=none
        endif
    endif
    endfunction
" }}}
```

Run it automatically when changing color scheme.

```
augroup mycolorschemes
    au!
    au ColorScheme * call FixColorscheme()
augroup END
```

And this helps to load your favorite-scheme-of-the-week on startup. (eek!! the default!)

```
if iSFirstRun == 1
    echo "HI"
    colo xoria256
    call FixColors()
endif
```

.. and this at the very top of .vimrc

```
"" To let us set some settings only once. {{{
    if exists("isRunning")
        let isFirstRun = 0
    else
        let isFirstRun = 1
    endif
    let isRunning = 1
" }}}
```

Perhaps there already is something for this 'isFirstRun'?

Comment: <sarcastic> Yeees, that looks much simpler, for a colorscheme you're using periodically :) ... Btw, if you don't want to change the original file (why?), why not just make a version 2 of it and change it in there. I really don't see why the need for all this problem making out of nothing.

Comment: There was no work in doing this compared to the annoyance of "manually" adjusting schemes as you change to them, or bringing along my changes to schemes as i update them (which i would have to manually do if i overwrote it or named it something else).

I'm glad for you that you are not as picky about your setup as I am.. ; )

Comment: Wow, great solution! +1 :) I eventually used a "sliced-up" version of this answer. It's based on this one so I didn't want to post a new answer for it. You can view it in my .vimrc: https://github.com/oryband/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Vim 8.2 help for posterity as this was my first search hit for this scenario:

```
To customize a color scheme use another name, e.g. ~/.vim/colors/mine.vim",
and use :runtime to load original color scheme:
    colors/evening.vim
    Statement ctermfg=Blue guifg=Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

The stock `synload.vim` file in `$VIM/vimXX/syntax/synload.vim` does a

```
runtime! syntax/syncolor.vim
```

This directs vim to read the given filespec in each directory of `runtimepath`. On RedHat systems, the runtimepath will be something like:

```
$HOIME/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim72,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after
```

Put your color adjustments in either `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim` or in the `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after/syntax` and you should be good to go.

While your adjustments can be simple `hi ...` directives, it's apparently more complicated. So I heavily borrowed from the stock `syncolor.vim` file and now have:

```
if !exists("syntax_cmd") || syntax_cmd == "on"
  " ":syntax on" works like in Vim 5.7: set colors but keep links
  command -nargs=* SynColor hi <args>
  command -nargs=* SynLink hi link <args>
else
  if syntax_cmd == "enable"
    " ":syntax enable" keeps any existing colors
    command -nargs=* SynColor hi def <args>
    command -nargs=* SynLink hi def link <args>
  elseif syntax_cmd == "reset"
    " ":syntax reset" resets all colors to the default
    command -nargs=* SynColor hi <args>
    command -nargs=* SynLink hi! link <args>
  else
    " User defined syncolor file has already set the colors.
    finish
  endif
endif

" Change comment color from bright cyan to gray
" The bold cyan conflicts with variables and other colors
if &background == "dark"
  SynColor Comment      term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Gray ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#80a0ff guibg=NONE
endif

delcommand SynColor
delcommand SynLink
```

Comment: Adding after/syntax/syncolor.vim worked for me.

Comment: @JeffSchwab uh, was that a confirmation of the utility of my answer?

Comment: The upvote was confirmation.  The comment was to say which part was specifically useful to me.

Answer (score -4):

Put

```
hi CursorLine    guibg=#000000 ctermbg=Black cterm=none
```

after your

```
colorscheme BusyBee
```

entry in your _vimrc.

Comment: @jdhao - You're commenting on an answer from almost ten years ago. A lot has changed since then ...