# Setting vim omnicompletion colors (Pmenu) in vimrc not working

Tags: vim

I am trying to customize my vim popup completion menu as per this guide:
[Vim Wiki: "Omni completion popup menu"](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion_popup_menu).  It notes

> add to your vimrc if you always want this choice.

However, with the following settings in my .vimrc file

```
colo desert

filetype plugin on
set ofu=syntaxcomplete#Complete
highlight Pmenu guibg=brown gui=bold
```

I get the following:

[image: Gahhhh! My eyes!]

Note: when I manually enter the highlight command manually, it works:

[image]

How do I get the popup to use a color scheme defined in .vimrc without having to enter it in manually each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [vim - Override colorscheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440149/override-colorscheme)

Short answer is that you can't. If you use a colorscheme, then all other color scheme tweaks in your .vimrc are ignored. The [AfterColors plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

if you put your commands in below sequence, you can get what you want. the syntax option will override your highlight option.

```
"" gui configuration
color murphy
syntax one
highlight Pmenu guibg=brown gui=bold
```

[image]

Comment: My version of this varied slightly to get it to work.  I'm using a Mac term.  
    color elflord  
    syntax on  
    highlight Pmenu ctermbg=242 guibg=DarkGrey

Comment: Fun fact -> You can see the complete highlight colors list with the command:

:highlight

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, most likely there is a highlighting command coming afterwards that is overriding your option. Probably when the filetype is determined and adjusts options. Try running it without the `filetype plugin on` option set.

If that works, you'll need to adjust the filetype detection to run your special options afterwards.