# vim ALE error highlighting not changing

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-ale

I am using a vim pluggin called ALE. But the error and warning highlighting does not go with my theme. So I am trying to change the colour or even switch it off, but nothing seems to work.

None of the following commands work when set in .vimrc

```
let g:ale_set_highlights = 0 " Disable highligting

highlight ALEWarning ctermbg=DarkMagenta 
highlight ALEError ctermbg=DarkMagenta

highlight ALEError ctermbg=none cterm=underline 
highlight ALEWarning ctermbg=none cterm=underline
```

This is what my vim highlight colour always looks like:

[image]

I am using: 'xterm-256color' 
And the highlighting only occurs on typescript files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override colorscheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440149/override-colorscheme).

Your plugin will be sourced after your `.vimrc`, so you can't override plugin colors like this.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I figured out that I had another linter running in the background :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another linter running in the background that would alter the settings.

Solved by removing that linter.

Comment: Do you know what linter was running that causing this? I'm having similar issues but with a Vue file.